# Force docker.service and docker.socket service to start after DNS is functioning on boot

Tags: networking, dns, services, docker

Using 18.04 LTS. To make a long story short, I'm using FreeIPA for my login service on my linux machines, which means I need DNS resolution to authenticate to the IPA server. However, my docker.socket is starting before DNS resolution is up and when docker.socket tries to resolve the docker "group" from IPA, it fails to resolve since its looking at the FreeIPA server and without DNS resolution it fails to resolve, which stops docker.socket from starting up properly. At least that is my theory up to this point.

I would like to force my docker.socket systemd service to start **AFTER** my DNS resolution is up.

My docker.socket and docker.service files are below. I have tried adding `After=`, `Requires=`, and various combinations of `sssd.service` to the `docker.socket` file and the `docker.service` and other various combinations of `systemd-resolved.service` along with the other various networking services/targets (e.g. `NetworkManager.service`, `network-online.target'), but I can't seem to get any of them to work correctly.

Is there a simple way of resolving this that I'm missing?

> Feb 06 14:11:00 aiml6 systemd[985]: **docker.socket: Failed to resolve
>   group docker:** Connection refused

```
docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2019-02-06 14:12:30 CST; 4min 53s ago
   Listen: /var/run/docker.sock (Stream)

Feb 06 14:09:30 aiml6 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
Feb 06 14:11:00 aiml6 systemd[1]: docker.socket: Starting timed out. Stopping.
Feb 06 14:11:00 aiml6 systemd[985]: docker.socket: Failed to resolve group docker: Connection refused
Feb 06 14:12:30 aiml6 systemd[1]: docker.socket: Stopping timed out (2). Killing.
Feb 06 14:12:30 aiml6 systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 06 14:12:30 aiml6 systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Docker Socket for the API.
```

docker.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
BindsTo=containerd.service
After=network-online.target firewalld.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this option.
TasksMax=infinity

# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

docker.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API
PartOf=docker.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing this same issue and also use FreeIPA. Was able to resolve it by adding:

```
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
```

to the `/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket` file (under `[Unit]` just like in the `docker.service` file)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and SSSD authentication on Windows Server LDAP
where my 'docker' group is defined.

Although it's not a DNS failure here, I get exactly the same error:

```
    docker.socket: Failed to resolve group docker: Connection refused
```

I've fixed it, by following this https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2710
defining an Override for the unit file /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket

sudo systemctl edit docker.socket

```
[Unit]
After=nss-user-lookup.target
DefaultDependencies=no
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else stumbles upon the same error message. I also received the error: `docker.socket: Failed to resolve group docker`. And for me the solution as posted in [this issue](https://github.com/vmware/photon/issues/965#issue-546891540) resolved the error:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```